# Basic things in Archimedean ordered fields

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

I'll write theorem first.

**Theorem:** Every Archimedean ordered field can be order-embedded into R.

***Proof:*** Let (K, ≤) be Archimedean. Then Q is dense in K. We define
φ : K → R as follows. For a ∈ K, let:
Ia = { r ∈ Q | r < a } and Ja = { s ∈ Q | s > a }.

There is some x ∈ R such that Ia ≤ x ≤ Ja, since R is Dedekind complete;
moreover, there is only one such x, by the density of Q in R. We may therefore
define φ(a) to be x.

For all a, b ∈ K,

φ(a + b) = φ(a) + φ(b),

φ(ab) = φ(a)φ(b)

ex. 1. Show that φ is a field embedding.
ex. 2. Show that φ preserves order.

Can someone tell me how can I simple show it?

Thx for help. Have a good day!

Comment: So if $a,b$ are elements of $K$, you have to prove the sets of inequalities $I_{a+b}<\varphi(a) + \varphi(b)<J_{a+b}$ and $I_{ab}<\varphi(a)\varphi(b)<J_{ab}$. It is enough to prove the second one for positive $a,b$.